# Find minimums of a 2D list by the absolute value

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a list that reads

```
alist={{-0.7681699655, 0.7373960565, -0.7373960565, 0.7681699655}, {-0.7430781170, 0.7229609036, -0.6069296501, 0.6270468636}, {-0.5667102509, 0.5590489168, -0.2406532537, 0.2483145877}, {-0.1208579429, 0.1289608681, -0.07672268364,0.06861975842}, {-0.05781298049, 0.08931404647, -0.08206351097,0.05056244499}, {-0.03742013870, 0.05996910069, -0.05996910069,0.03742013870}, {-0.02094729733, -0.02965689326, 0.02838464090,0.02221954970}, {-0.0007664772180, -0.05347349201, 0.1208618572, -0.06662188802}, {0.3454536140, -0.3939473484, 0.6595390083, -0.6110452740}, {0.6342722531, -0.6745157548, 0.7845209706, -0.7442774690}, {-0.7681699655,0.7373960565, -0.7373960565, 0.7681699655}};
```

I would like to find two numbers from each pair of internal brackets that has the smallest absolute values. So that my output casts

```
minalist={{0.7373960565, -0.7373960565},{-0.6069296501, 0.6270468636}, ...}
```

I have tried using `Min` and `MinimalBy[alist, Abs]` but the results are for the whole list and not for each internal bracket. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** First define a function for a single list:

```
minabs2[expr_]:=MinimalBy[expr,Abs,2];
```

Then use [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) to apply `minabs2` to each element of the list, that is, each inner list:

```
Map[minabs2,alist]
```

**Option 2:** As a one-liner:

```
Map[MinimalBy[#,Abs,2]&,alist]
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Is it also possible to `Sort` these data points for each internal bracket after performing `Map`?

Comment: +1 To also `Sort` use `Sort@*(MinimalBy[#, Abs, 2] &) /@ alist` or `Sort /@ (MinimalBy[#, Abs, 2] & /@ alist)`

Comment: Thank you @BobHanlon!

Comment: If you want to sort by absolute value, then it turns out that `MinimalBy[#,Abs,2]&` already does that, as explained in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinimalBy.html). If you want to sort in the usual sense, see the comment of @BobHanlon. I recommend looking at the [documentation of `Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) which is an extremely useful command once you know it.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for your suggestion!